# Forward unix datagram sockets with ssh?

Tags: sockets, ssh, datagram, tunnel

Is it possible to forward datagram sockets with ssh? It seems the default behavior is to forward or create a stream socket. I am attempting to write to a remote unix datagram socket with python. Tried to use ssh to forward the socket so i could write locally with python....this works but only seems to work with stream sockets :(

Comment: Have a look at `socat` a powerful tool to transport data between different endpoints type, which you can run alongside an ssh tunnel if you need it.

Comment: Thanks, we will revisit socat, during initial troubleshooting we used socat on the remote machine to transfer from stream to datagram. We ran into a bunch of issues getting json messages split into two pieces. Even after adjusting the byte max -b option..we will take another stab at it thanks again...

Comment: You are transmitting JSON data over UDP? Except if you add some guarantees in your protocol (basically the one offered by TCP like packets ordering and retransmission), you will always have the risk of corrupting your data if your JSON payload does not fit inside a single UDP packet.

Answer (score -2):

You have an example here: https://stackpointer.io/network/ssh-port-forwarding-tcp-udp/365/ based on `ssh` + `socat`:

1. do your ssh port redirection, like: `ssh -L 8000:127.0.0.1:8000 user@server01`
2. run `socat` to transmit UDP to TCP port 8000: `socat -T15 udp4-recvfrom:53000,reuseaddr,fork tcp:localhost:8000`

The article then speaks about `ssf` (https://securesocketfunneling.github.io/ssf/) which I never heard about but claims to do both UDP and TCP redirections, so that could be another idea for you.